# OpenLDAP Multi master

Tags: ldap, replication

Is anybody have faced with this error:  **ldap_initialize(ldap://ds2.domain.com=cn=admin,cn=config) failed (-9)**

My configuration: two LDAP master servers ldap://ds1.domain.com and ldap://ds2.domain.com with master-master replication.

Both servers have this in log file:

```
slap_client_connect: ldap_initialize(ldap://ds2.domain.com=cn=admin,cn=config) failed (-9)
do_syncrepl: rid=002 rc -9 retrying
daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
daemon: activity on:
daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
=>do_syncrepl rid=002
slap_client_connect: ldap_initialize(ldap://ds2.domain.com=cn=admin,cn=config) failed (-9)
daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
daemon: activity on:
daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
do_syncrepl: rid=002 rc -9 retrying (4 retries left)
daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
=>do_syncrepl rid=002
slap_client_connect: ldap_initialize(ldap://ds2.domain.com=cn=admin,cn=config) failed (-9)
do_syncrepl: rid=002 rc -9 retrying (3 retries left)
daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
daemon: activity on:
daemon: epoll: listen=8 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=9 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
daemon: epoll: listen=10 active_threads=0 tvp=zero
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error:

```
ds2.domain.com=cn=admin,cn=config

      here -> =cn=
```

Comment: ... in the configuration of the `syncrepl` client.